# Firebase data structure ideas

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm working in a POS system and I'm using Firebase for the backend. One of the reports I need to make is "most/less sold products".

I have my structures like this `/sales/`:

```
"1234": {
    "date": 1234567890, // timestamp
    "products": {
        "coca-cola-clasica-355-ml": {
            "quantity": 3,
            "salesPrice": 500,
            "costPrice": 400
        },
        "coca-cola-clasica-600-ml": {
            "quantity": 6,
            "salesPrice": 900,
            "costPrice": 700
        }
    },
    "subtotal": 6400,
    "total": 6400
},
"5678": {
    "date": 1234567890, // timestamp
    "products": {
        "taqueritos-chile-picante": {
            "quantity": 2,
            "salesPrice": 100,
            "costPrice": 80
        },
        "coca-cola-clasica-600-ml": {
            "quantity": 4,
            "salesPrice": 900,
            "costPrice": 700
        }
    },
    "subtotal": 200,
    "total": 200
}
```

And /products/:

```
{
    "coca-cola-clasica-355-ml": {
        "costPrice": 350,
        "name": "Coca Cola Clasica 355 ml",
        "salesPrice": 500,
        "stock": 99,
        "supplier": "femsa-coca-cola",
        "tax": false,
    },
    "coca-cola-clasica-600-ml": {
        "costPrice": 700,
        "name": "Coca Cola Clasica 600 ml",
        "salesPrice": 900,
        "stock": 99,
        "supplier": "femsa-coca-cola",
        "tax": false,
    },
    "taqueritos-chile-picante": {
        "costPrice": 80,
        "name": "Taqueritos Chile Picante",
        "salesPrice": 100,
        "stock": 500,
        "supplier": "dinant",
        "tax": true
    }
}
```

So if I have to get the "most sold products" right now I have to iterate over all the sales and add quantity every time I found a product, after that order the results and get the most sold products and that sucks.

I have two ideas to fix this:

1. Add a property to the `/products/` like "soldTimes" and add quantity every time the product is sold.
2. Create a third entity call like `soldProducts` and count the quantity of sold products for each one every time a client buy one.

Is any of this 2 approach valid? I'm I missing something in Firebase?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NoSQL you typically end up modeling your data for the way your application wants to consume it. So if your app needs to have a list of most sold products, you should consider storing that list in the database.

```
productLeaderboard: {
    coca-cola-clasica-355-ml: {
        totalQuantity: 3,
        totalSalesPrice: 500,
        totalCost: 400,
        totalProfit: 100
    },
    ...
}
```

Now to find the most sold products, you can simply do:

```
ref.child('productLeaderboard').orderByChild('totalQuantity').limitToFirst(3).on(...
```